# How to get clean website url with php?

Tags: php, url

I'm using $wsurl as my websites clean url $wsurl = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'; But recently when I want to echo it from websites admin panel it gave me result:

http://localhost/admin/>http://localhost/?page=166

instead of

http://localhost/?page=166

**More Detailed**

What i use: `<a target="_blank" href="><?=$wsurl?>?page=<?=$new_id?>">Link</a>`

What i get as html output `<a target="_blank" href=">localhost/?page=170">Link</a>`

But when i click it from admin panel, it opens page `localhost/admin>http://localhost/?page=170` (instead of `http://localhost/?page=170`) which doesn't exist at all

How to deal with that problem?

I want to get websites main url from everywhere within ws.
For ex, if i'm in admin panel http://localhost/admin/index.php the $wsurl will be http://localhost/

If my admin panels url looks like http://mydomain.com/admin/index.php the $wsurl will be http://mydomain.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are facing issues like that then you can try this :

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
echo 'http://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . '/';
```

Comment: Still getting something like that http://localhost/admin>http://localhost/?page=170

Comment: The problem is i'm getting true result <a target="" href=">http://localhost/?page=173">Link</a> but when i click it from admin panel which located in localhost/admin opens page  localhost/admin>http://localhost/?page=170 . But it must open page http://localhost/?page=170 from everywhere inside website

Comment: what is the extact code you use and what is the extact output you get?

Comment: What i use: `<a target="_blank"  href="><?=$wsurl?>?page=<?=$new_id?>">Link</a>`  What i get as html output `<a target="_blank" href=">localhost/?page=170">Link</a>` But when i click, it opens page  `localhost/admin>localhost/?page=170` which doesn't exist at all

Comment: It already has http:// inside:  `$wsurl = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';`

Comment: OK... then try this <a target="_blank" href="<?=$wsurl?>?page=<?=$new_id?>">Link</a> ...you see in your code there is a ">" after href=" which will append the current url there thinking it is null

Comment: In your code it is  href="><?=$wsurl?> and mine  href="<?=$wsurl?> ...check the sign after the qoute